# SwiftUI iPhone Landscape by default shows navigation on top

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, landscape, navigationview

Here I show the code of contentView and signUp File. In contentView you can see navigationView I used for the navigation setup purpose but what happens here is that when I run the app on the iPhone portraits then it's working fine, but it shows some unwanted white bar in iPhone landscape. One thing I notice is that It's working fine in iPad landscape and portraits.

iphone 11 pro landscape:

[image]

iphone 11 pro portraits:

[image]

iPad Pro 9.7 portraits:

[image]

iPad Pro 9.7 landscape:

[image]

See the above images issue in 11 pro landscape

ContentView.swift

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
              NavigationView {
                ZStack {
                    VStack
                        {
                            VStack {
                                signupTop()
                                    .background(SwiftUI.Color("top"))
                            }
                            Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack {
                            VStack {
                                signUp()
                                    .background(SwiftUI.Color.white)
                                    .cornerRadius(5.0)
                                    .shadow(color: Color.gray, radius: 5.0)
                            }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 75, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))
                            
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                    
                }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
            .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .compact)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
```

signUp.swift

```
NavigationLink(destination: signInContent()) {
                                Text("Sign In")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("top"))
                                    .font(Font.subheadline.weight(.bold))
                            }
                            .isDetailLink(false)
```